# Access to django template variable from js block

Tags: javascript, python, django, gruntjs, django-templates

I have js code in my django template but project use Grunt js, so code must be in js block {% block extrajs %}.

This is my code in template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pub_date = {{ obj.pub_date|date:'YmdHi' }};
    var hour = moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();
    var time_ago = moment(pub_date, "YYYYMMDDhhmm").locale('{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}').fromNow();
    document.write(time_ago);
</script>
```

Here I try test my code but without success, I get empty alert window:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pub_date = '{{ obj.pub_date|date:'YmdHi' }}';
    alert(pub_date);
});
```

Question is, how I can get access from js block to variable in template?

Comment: Can you try this?  var pub_date = {{obj.pub_date|date:'YmdHi'|safe}};

Answer (score 0):

In order to this work you have to have your js code inside your html template. Also when trying to do this add `|safe` behind your statement. For example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pub_date = '{{ obj.pub_date|date:'YmdHi'|safe }}';
    alert(pub_date);
});
```

Comment: I have my js code in inside my template but your solution doesn't work. Still empty alert window.